# Python warning :FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting below warning for python in console.I did not found any solution for these.We dont want to suppress warnings .
Also we have a big code base setup.how to know which code block is cause of this error as warning dont give code line number.
I am using below version of python and numpy.Is it due to old verison's of python and numpy.

Python version- 3.6.8
Numpy Version-  1.19.5
matplotlib version is 3.3.4
pandas version is 1.1.5

Warning:

/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py:1402: FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.

python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1743: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: The error is coming from matplotlib, what version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: @Rob.  matplotlib version is 3.3.4 and pandas version is 1.1.5   ..there are some warnings related to pandas also I have  mentioned in the original post

Comment: It would help to have the whole traceback available. Probably the error is somewhere down the stack.

Answer (score 6):

The below works:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(obj)[:, None]
```

Comment: Just in case someone else encounters the same problem with mine, I wrote a comment.

When one uses `(obj)[:, np.newaxis]`, there will a same warning coming out, where obj is a `numpy.ndarray`. We can do the same modification like `np.array(obj)[:, np.newaxis]` to eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Do what the error message suggests: "Convert to a numpy array before indexing." That is, append `.values` call to the pandas data frame columns that you are plotting.

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you're accessing the array, using slicing. Matplotlib is going to remove that from how they handle arrays, but they haven't yet. It's just a recommendation to convert to a different type of array access, like Numpy, before that happens. Based of what you're showing, i'd guess it's as simple as 1. Create Numpy Array 2. Use identical slicing except using Numpy syntax. Should be good to go after that I'd imagine.